How do I configure the terraform aws_eks_addon aws-ebs-csi-driver volumeAttachLimit
I read this doc
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_addon
about the aws_eks_addon and how to pass it configuration_values
Then I read this doc on how to get the schema for those values using describe-addon-configuration
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/describe-addon-configuration.html
I found the volumeAttachLimit and coded up this terraform based on the schema
resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs_csi_driver" {
  addon_name    = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  cluster_name  = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  addon_version = try(var.addon_versions.ebs_csi_driver, null)
  configuration_values = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      node = {
        properties = {
          volumeAttachLimit = {
            minimum = 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

But when I apply I get this error:
 operation error EKS: UpdateAddon, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: df42e7e0-f96b-48f1-9359-cf8c29a188cc, InvalidParameterException: ConfigurationValue provided in request is not supported: Json schema validation failed with error: [$.properties: is not defined in the schema and the schema does not allow additional properties]

Feels like maybe there is toplevel hierarchy I am missing. Since I know properties is in fact in the schema.  Or maybe I am supposed to use addition_args somehow to send in overrides?  The docs don't mention that, but docs will be docs.
Thanks to @MedAgou I got the answer...  It has to be like this
resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs_csi_driver" {
  addon_name    = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  cluster_name  = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  addon_version = try(var.addon_versions.ebs_csi_driver, null)
  configuration_values = jsonencode({
    node = {
      volumeAttachLimit = 20
    }
  })
}


You don't need to specify the first properties it should be like this :
resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs_csi_driver" {
  addon_name    = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  cluster_name  = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  addon_version = try(var.addon_versions.ebs_csi_driver, null)
  configuration_values = jsonencode({
      node = {
          volumeAttachLimit = {
            minimum = 20
          }
      }
  })
}


No, in the schema is integer :            "volumeAttachLimit":{
"default":null,
"description":"Overrides the maximum number of volumes that can be attached per node (for all nodes)",
"minimum":0,
"type":[
"integer",
"null"
]
}

Thanks, you put me on the right path.  Turns out, I had to remove both of the properties entries... and the minimum was actually saying the min value.  So I guess they have their own implementation of schema, or I just don't know schema as well as I thought I did.  Anyway, this worked.resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs_csi_driver" {   addon_name    = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"   cluster_name  = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name   addon_version = try(var.addon_versions.ebs_csi_driver, null)   configuration_values = jsonencode({     node = {       volumeAttachLimit = 20     }   }) }

@MedAgou Guess I can't format code in a comment.  I edited the question to add  the final answer... if you want to edit yours I can mark it as the answer.  Thanks for putting me on the right path.

terraform code edited as worked for you, glad that help
